# How to create a Redis cache in startup on user OnSignedIn event?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4, stackexchange.redis

.NET CORE 3.1

I got an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59667059/how-to-logout-all-clients-from-identity-server) how to logout all clients from Identity Server.

I work by this [example](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/net-development/using-auth-cookies-in-asp-net-core/) (chapter) REVOCATION.

But now I have a new problem. 
On OnSignedIn event I want to add the user id to the Redis Cache, but I dont know how.

This is a bad practice:

```
var sp = services.BuildServiceProvider();
var cache = sp.GetService<IDistributedCache>();
cache.SetString("helloFromRedis", "world");
var valueFromRedis = cache.GetString("helloFromRedis");
Console.WriteLine(valueFromRedis);
```

My Startup.cs

```
public class Startup
{
   public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
   {
       Configuration = configuration;
   }

   public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   {
     services.AddStackExchangeRedisCache(options =>
     {
        options.Configuration = RedisString;
     });


     services.AddAuthentication(options =>
     {
        options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";                              
     })
      .AddCookie("Cookies", options =>
      {
         options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;                   
         options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
         options.SlidingExpiration = true;
         options.Events.OnSignedIn(a => {
               // there I want to resolve cache and put userId from claims.
         });
      })
      .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
       {
        //...
      });
   }
```

How I can resolve Redis cache?

Comment: You must have an endpoint that is called when the user authenticates. You should not use services inside that event, it's meant for debugging. Use the endpoint and inject `IDistributedCache` there and then cache what ever you need.

Comment: @alsami How I can create endpoint? After success login Identity Server redirects to /signin-oidc, and after that app redirects to previous page. I can't handle /signin-oidc endpoint.

Comment: Don't you have a login callback registered?
http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/signin.html#login-workflow

Comment: @alsami I have registered in mvc client options.CallbackPath = "/callback-login"; In Nginx logs for login method: POST 302, but Console doesn't write word and client redirects to previous page. 
        [HttpPost("callback-login")]
        public IActionResult Login()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("<<< Ok >>>");
            return Ok();           
        }

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
o.Events.OnSignedIn = ctx =>
{
    var cache = ctx.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IDistributedCache>();
    return  Task.CompletedTask;
};
```

`RequestServices` property is an instance of `IServiceProvider`.