# How to redirect User to local login, and after that to IdentityServer?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I work with .Net Core 3.1 mvc app, Nodejs app and IdentityServer.

Mvc app authenticates with IdentityServer and return to previous link. I don't have local /login end point.

I need if user open secured link, he will redirect to my local login in Mvc Client, and after that automatically redirects to IdentityServer login page.

Mvc client LoginPath works only without AddOpenIdConnect:

```
 .AddCookie("Cookies", options =>
 {
   options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
});
```

I know about UserIreatction feature on IdentityServer Startup:

```
services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
{
options.UserInteraction.LoginUrl = new PathString("/Account/Login");
}
```

But I have two client apps, the first is Nodejs app, and the second - .netcore mvc. 
It will be work with both apps. And that will be problems for nodejs app. There I can't modify existing nodejs rootes.

How to add login path in mvc client, that user if will open secured page - firstly redirects to local login?

Thanks.

Comment: The user has to login twice? First local and then on IdentityServer? Please note that the client is not supposed to request the user's credentials. The only flow that supports this is the Resource Owner Password Flow (ROPC), which is sort of deprecated. The user should always login on the IdentityServer website.

Comment: @RuardvanElburg no. I use backChannelLogout. When user logged in two clients with Idsrv then after logout the second mvc client stay active. After refresh page it continue itself session. You [wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59672775/4205374) about cache. I want with cache remove cookie. Mvc client: if was clicked secured link - user redirects to IdentityServer and after login - returns to previous. Where put code `_cache.set(...)` if I can't catch login endpoint, because mvc doesn't have it. Therefore I wanted to create local login what redirect to Idrsv, and after return will write cache.

Comment: There are options inside the client. Take a look at the [article here](https://damienbod.com/2018/12/18/openid-connect-back-channel-logout-using-azure-redis-cache-and-identityserver4/), search for CookieEventHandler.

Comment: @RuardvanElburg thanks for answer. Your example doesn't work in 3.x version, because Redis Cache [DI](https://github.com/damienbod/AspNetCoreBackChannelLogout/blob/05d51cd79fe9e7c8cff69003964bd193201efe3c/MvcHybridBackChannelTwo/LogoutSessionManager.cs#L13) works only in Startup Configure action and Controllers. In [ConfigureServices](https://github.com/damienbod/AspNetCoreBackChannelLogout/blob/05d51cd79fe9e7c8cff69003964bd193201efe3c/MvcHybridBackChannelTwo/Startup.cs#L72) - DI doesn't work.  But I have solved with middlewares. Now if logouted one client - the second client is logouted too.